# Log likelihood ratio text analysis

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I'm not sure if I've been using the Dunning log likelihood statistic to correctly identify characteristic keywords. I calculated the LogLikelihood values as $ G2 = 2*((a*ln \frac{a}{E1})) + (b*ln \frac{b}{E2}))) $ but now I'm confused on how to use this information to label `word` as more characteristic of TextA vs TextB.

I've seen:

$H_{0} =$ `word` is evenly distributed in both texts

$H_{a} = $ `word` is not evenly distributed between the texts (ie, it's overrepresented in one)

For example, suppose I've calculated the LL of `word` to be 23.54. This would be statistically significant at a significance level of 0.05.

What I've been doing is labeling `word` as characteristic of textA if it has a statistically significant LL and characteristic of textB otherwise. Correct?

Note: I already understand the TFIDF method

---

[Relevant material, although please post relevant material too](https://de.dariah.eu/tatom/feature_selection.html)

Comment: you will compare your log-likelihood-ratio to a threshold. depending on the problem and according to Neyman-Pearson Lemma, there exists a certain threshold such that a certain false alarm rate is always satisfied. Neyman Pearson Lemma tells us that among all such thresholds there exists one which maximizes the detection probability. This is the optimum testing strategy with respect to NP Lemma. So from your samples your calculate the log-likelihood-ratio and compare it to a threshold. It it exceeds the threshold then you accept $H_\alpha$ else you accept $H_0$.

Comment: That doesn't establish which text it is over represented in though, unless I'm missing that bit

Comment: "but now I'm confused on how to use this information to label word as more characteristic of TextA vs TextB." what is your question?

Comment: how to use the log likelihood to determine if a word is more characteristic of TextA vs TextB.

Comment: You will multiply the original threshold with $P_0/P_1$ which is the ratio of the a priori probabilities of $H_0$ and $H_1$, before comparing it to your likelihood ratio.

Comment: Can you give an example. I've never seen anything concrete on it

Comment: Bayesian hypothesis testing. Please check this in Google. It is just the application of Bayes rule.

Comment: so first you see if the LL is greater than a threshold (7.88, for example) and then see which text it has a greater relative frequency in?